# 2D boundary value problem for planetary lander

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations, boundary-conditions, optimization

I'm solving a 2D lander guidance problem where a planetary lander must be guided to a safe landing spot on an arbitrary terrain. The specific method I'm coding use methods similar to RRT/RRT* motion planning methods. One of the steps in this algorithm is to predict if a trajectory exists between two states and connect them.

The specific problem is 2D planetary lander simulation. The only external force is the gravitational acceleration $g_{planet}$ (assumed constant).

**Given:** The two endpoint boundary constraints are:

- $\textbf{r}_0$ and $\textbf{r}_f$ : initial and final position.
- $\textbf{v}_0$ and $\textbf{v}_f$ : initial and final velocity.
- $P_0$ and $P_f$ : initial and final thrust acceleration.
- $\theta_0$ and $\theta_f$ : initial and final lander orientation.
- Note: lander orientation is independent from thrust acceleration.

**Goal:** Find the optimal trajectory between points in terms of:

- thrust acceleration function $P(t)$
- lander orientation function $\theta(t)$
- optimal time of flight $\tau$
- Optimization objective: minimize integral thrust $ J = \int_{0}^{\tau} P(t) dt $

**Question:** Assuming time of flight $\tau$ is known, does an analytical method exists to obtain the $P(t)$ and $R(t)$ functions? If so, does that step allow optimization of $\tau$ based on the given objective min(J)?

I have solved the problem with an iterative Newton-Raphson approach but this is much too costly for my code. I would be grateful for any hint on this.

[image: Schematic of the trajectory problem]

Comment: What are you trying to optimize? In other words, what's the objective function?  I can't tell from your description.

Comment: A diagram woukd be useful,  IMO...

Comment: Yes. Of course sorry. I'll edit the question to add the information.

Comment: Is there a way to open the topic again? I tried to edit down to the specific question.